# Oracle : Convert DD-MM-YYYY to MON-YYYY

Tags: sql, database, oracle

In the following code `SDate ='10-04-2020'` format is DD-MM-YYYY and I need only the month and the year to compare it with the given date which is MON-YYYY

```
SELECT WR.EmpID AS EMPSID, SUM(WR.ESALARY) AS TOTAL_SALARY
FROM WEEKLY_REPORT WR
WHERE WR.EmpID = 'E009' AND TO_CHAR(WR.SDate,'MON-YYYY') = TO_CHAR('APR-2020','MON-YYYY') 
GROUP BY WR.EmpID;
```

the error
`ORA-01722: invalid number`

Comment: What is the data type of `SDate`? Assuming it's date, you shouldn't use `to_char()` and `to_date` and format models anywhere. Instead, you should compare `SDate` to fixed dates ( `>= date '2020-04-01'` and `< date '2020-05-01'`) in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Since your date is in dd-mm-yyyy format you need to use `to_date(WR.SDate,'dd-mm-yyyy')` before using to_char() on it. And instead of  `TO_CHAR('APR-2020','MON-YYYY')` use 'APR-2020' which is a valid string.

```
SELECT WR.EmpID AS EMPSID, SUM(WR.ESALARY) AS TOTAL_SALARY
FROM WEEKLY_REPORT WR
WHERE WR.EmpID = 'E009' AND TO_CHAR(to_date(WR.SDate,'dd-mm-yyyy'),'MON-YYYY') = 'APR-2020' 
GROUP BY WR.EmpID;
```

DB-Fiddle:

Query to convert date to mon-yyyy:

```
 select TO_CHAR(to_date('10-04-2020','dd-mm-yyyy'),'MON-YYYY') result from dual
```

Output:

| RESULT |
| --- |
| APR-2020 |

Query to check the condition:

```
 select 'true' result  from dual
 where TO_CHAR(to_date('10-04-2020','dd-mm-yyyy'),'MON-YYYY') = 'APR-2020'
```

Output:

| RESULT |
| --- |
| true |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5f7d87a867c694505d3bc3c6a8ee823d)*

Answer (score 1):

Is `SDate` a date?  If so, it does not have a format.  It doesn't make sense to pass a character string to `to_char`.  'APR-2020' is already a string.

Either compare a string to a string

```
TO_CHAR(WR.SDate,'MON-YYYY') = 'APR-2020'
```

Or compare a date to a date

```
trunc( wr.SDate, 'MM' ) = date '2020-04-01'
```